# Transformers: How to override subclass

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I need to override a subclass but I am not sure how to do it:

```
RuntimeError: Passing `optimizers` is not allowed if Fairscale, Deepspeed or PyTorch FSDP is enabled.

You should subclass `Trainer` and override the `create_optimizer_and_scheduler` method.
```

Here is a limited example making use of deepspeed

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, Trainer, TrainingArguments,  DataCollatorWithPadding
from transformers.optimization import Adafactor, AdafactorSchedule
import torch

# model
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased", 
                                                           num_labels=2,
                                                           torch_dtype=torch.float16,
                                                           )

# adafactor
optimizer = Adafactor(model.parameters(), scale_parameter=True, relative_step=True, warmup_init=True, lr=None)
lr_scheduler = AdafactorSchedule(optimizer)

# training args
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./xd',
    num_train_epochs=4,
    per_device_train_batch_size=32,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=32*2,
    learning_rate=1e-4,
    warmup_steps=500,
    tf32=True,
    bf16=False,
    fp16=True,
    dataloader_num_workers=16,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=1,
    evaluation_strategy='steps',
    eval_steps=2500,
    save_steps=1000,
    deepspeed=r'ds_config_zero3.json',
    disable_tqdm=False,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir='./xd_logs',
    logging_steps=1000,
)

# init trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    optimizers = (optimizer, lr_scheduler),  # want to use this
)
```

It wants me to override this:

```
    def create_optimizer_and_scheduler(self, num_training_steps: int):
        """
        Setup the optimizer and the learning rate scheduler.

        We provide a reasonable default that works well. If you want to use something else, you can pass a tuple in the
        Trainer's init through `optimizers`, or subclass and override this method (or `create_optimizer` and/or
        `create_scheduler`) in a subclass.
        """
        self.create_optimizer()
        if IS_SAGEMAKER_MP_POST_1_10 and smp.state.cfg.fp16:
            # If smp >= 1.10 and fp16 is enabled, we unwrap the optimizer
            optimizer = self.optimizer.optimizer
        else:
            optimizer = self.optimizer
        self.create_scheduler(num_training_steps=num_training_steps, optimizer=optimizer)
```

But I dont know what that would look like considering I want to pass this in to the `Trainer`

```
    optimizers = (optimizer, lr_scheduler),  # want to use this
```